# VS Code Python Extension Failed to Activate

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The Python extension is failing to load for me. I noticed it was updated earlier this morning and I haven't changed my VS Code configuration or added any new extensions. Any suggestions?

Here is the output of the extension:

```
[ERROR 2023-1-6 11:16:39.302]: extension activation failed [TypeError: Expected a string, got undefined
    at e.exports (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:1980955)
    at b (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:138478)
    at y.update (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:133796)
    at y.initialize (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:137868)
    at new y (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:128788)
    at y.getInstance (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:129446)
    at h.getSettings (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:140722)
    at c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:409217
    at async t.activateComponents (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:408578)
    at async c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:3124940
    at async e (c:\Users\tmorg\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.2.0\out\client\extension.js:2:3124490)
    at async f.n (c:\Users\tmorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:6818)
    at async f.m (c:\Users\tmorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:6781)
    at async f.l (c:\Users\tmorg\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:6238)]
```

[image]

Comment: Honestly, sounds like you should contact the extension maintainers and report this as a bug. The best we can do here is google if a bug has already been reported and then link you to it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (at least it seemed the same), however it is possible to work around it if you are using the Python extension in conjunction with Remote Debugging.

You can ignore the extension's activation failure if that is your primary use, since VSCode is still able to debug remotely using Python Remote Attach.

---

After some more work on this, I found that updating the Python Extension to the pre-release version cleared up the various errors that came with the recent updates.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, @BrodyCritchlow.  I've reworded the original answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll back to the historical version in the extension store to solve this problem.

If you want, you can also follow [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20652) on github, it's the same problem.

[image]